# RxJS throttle trailing and leading configuration

Tags: rxjs

I have a question on RxJS throttle.

When I set up leading: true, trailing: false:

```js
const result = interval(1000).pipe(
  throttle(() => interval(2000), { leading: true, trailing: false })
);

result.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

I will get 2, 4, 6, 8 and it is correct.

When I set up leading: false, trailing: true:

```js
const result = interval(1000).pipe(
  throttle(() => interval(2000), { leading: false, trailing: true })
);

result.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

I will get 0, 3, 6 and it is correct.

When I set up for leading: true, trailing: true:

```js
const result = interval(1000).pipe(
  throttle(() => interval(2000), { leading: true, trailing: true })
);

result.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

I thought I will get above two scenarios result combined. But I will get 0, 2, 4, 6, which I do not understand.

Comment: `throttle` makes sure there's not emission until the inner Observable emits so you can't have a combination of both results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check out the source to see why it behaves this way ([throttle.ts](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7.5.5/src/internal/operators/throttle.ts)).

The **leading** config parameter is only referenced once, in the **onNext** callback function created when the source is subscribe to.  That function it checks if the operator is waiting on an observable based on **durationSelector** (called **throttled**), and if it is not, will call **send** if **leading** is *true*.

```
// from onNext callback
!(throttled && !throttled.closed) && (leading ? send() : startThrottle(value));
```

The **send** function emits and calls **startThrottle**, while **startThrottle** creates the **throttled** observable.

```
// from send
subscriber.next(value);
!isComplete && startThrottle(value); // creates throttled.
```

So here's the important part, after **throttled** completes and **trailing** is true, **send** is called just like the **onNext** callback does when **leading** is *true*.  What this effectively does is create a loop that as soon as **throttled** is done a new **throttled** is created.

```
// from endThrottling (which is throttle's onNext callback)
throttled = null; // no more throttled
if (trailing) {
  send(); // going to create throttled again.
```

The only way to avoid this loop is if the source emits after the **durationSelector**.  If there is no value ready to emit, then **send** won't call **startValue**, so the next call to **send** will have to come from the original **onNext** callback.